# Is it possible to run a Git hook after adding a file to a project?

Tags: git, githooks

Is it pssobile to run a git hook after adding a file?  For example, after running:

```
git add someFile.php
```

a script would be triggered.

Comment: The first available hook should be the "pre-commit hook". As it says, it's invoked on git commit.

Comment: I'd like the hook to fire before commiting, but after running `git add someFile.php`.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot postpone the operations ? By the way, there is no hook associated to git add [cit.](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git help hooks
```

Will show you all the currently available hooks.  As of Git 1.7, there is no hook that's invoked when you add a file, so I'm afraid the answer to your question is "no."